# Can i turn on location service by the code programmatically

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager, tvos, tvos9.1

I am new to the tvOS platform. I want to know how to get current location latitude and longitude at the application launch. I am writing this code to get the location coordinate.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            self.locationManager.delegate = self
            self.locationManager.requestLocation()
            self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
        return true
    }

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        locationValue = manager.location?.coordinate
        print("=========didUpdateLocations==========Latitude>>>>>",locationValue.latitude)
        print("=========didUpdateLocations==========Longitude>>>>",locationValue.longitude)
    }
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {

        print("localizedDescription===================",error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

This code provide the coordinate after the view controller loads. While my requirement is that I want to get coordinate ***before*** loading the view controller. Can i enable location service programmatically for single application?

Answer (score 1):

The location service determines the location on demand and it requires time to do so. For that reason, it only offers an asynchronous interface.

So there is now way you can retrieve the location before the view controller is shown. You will need to write your app such that it can display the view controller without knowing the location and later update the screen when the location information is available.

Answer (score 0):

It requires setting the app information and grants, see the discussion [Here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18842)

I also found the solution and explanation for this identical question [Here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/111314#111314)

Comment: @ Frank i have done. But is not get location quickly. The delegate method is delaying to respond the location. while the application started. I want to get coordinate before  the application launch

Comment: OK, understand.. I'll take a look a bit later.

Comment: You can send the demo application on this email id : sankalap@fusionitechnologies.com

Comment: Not going to do a demo application, was going to look to see if I can find a solution.